# Roblox Studio: DataStore request was added to queue

Tags: roblox, luau

Basically I'm trying to make a banscript, but whenever I hit play on Roblox Studio it tells me the follwing:

> DataStore request was added to queue. If request queue fills, further requests will be dropped.

And any Datastore changes I try to make using scripts do not do anything.
(I am only saving boolean values so it's not too much data!)
BanHandler

```
    local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
    local BanDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("BanDataStore")
          
    script.Parent.Ban.Event:Connect(function(Player : Player)
        BanDataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId, true)
        print(tostring(Player.UserId).." has been banned!")
        Player:Kick("Banned.")
    end)
          
    script.Parent.Unban.Event:Connect(function(Player : Player)
        BanDataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId, false)
    end)
```

DatastoreHandler
-- DatastoreHandler

```
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
        local DatastoreService  = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
        local BanDataStore = DatastoreService:GetDataStore("BanDataStore")
           
        BanDataStore:SetAsync(2528182795, false)
        
           
           
        local UserId = player.UserId
        local result = BanDataStore:GetAsync(UserId)
             
                     
        if result then
            player:Kick("You have been banned from this game!")
        end
                    
        if not result then
            BanDataStore:SetAsync(UserId, false)
        end
    end)
```

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Warnings like this are the ones you don't need to worry about; no one is going to ban a lot of people that quickly. Are you trying to ban many people in a short amount of time? As far as I know, even if you make 2 requests one will get added to queue.

Comment: That really wasn't the main thing, the banhandler doesn't save anything to the datastore, that is my problem. Thanks, still!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this because you are setting your own account to be unbanned?

```
BanDataStore:SetAsync(2528182795, false)
```

Try commenting this out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving boolean values to create a ban script you can just use a table of banned player ids and iterate through it. For example,

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local bannedPlayers = {
    -- Include player IDs of people that you want banned
    
}

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    for i, v in pairs(bannedPlayers) do
        if v == player.UserId then
            player:Kick()
        end
    end
    
end)
```

If you want to tie this in with a data store for some reason then you could do

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local BanDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("BanDataStore")

local bannedPlayers = {
    -- Include player IDs of people that you want banned
    1366289010 -- My UserID lol
}

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local playerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId
    local data = {}
    
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        data = BanDataStore:GetAsync(playerUserId, data)
    end)
    
    if success then
        for i, v in pairs(data) do
            if v == player.UserId then
                player:Kick()
        
            end
            
        end
        
    end
    
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local playerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId
    
    local data = bannedPlayers
    
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        BanDataStore:SetAsync(playerUserId, data)
    end)
    
    if success then
        print("Data saved successfully!")
    else
        warn(errormessage)
    end
    
end)
```

I'm kind of confused on the .Event code you wrote but you could alter your ban event and unban event to work with this data store by putting

```
script.Parent.Ban.Event:Connect(function(Player : Player)
    table.insert(bannedPlayers, Player.UserId)
end)

script.Parent.Unban.Event:Connect(function(Player : Player)
    table.remove(bannedPlayers, Player.UserId)
end)
```

Hope this helps! If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.